# grep with negative pattern

Tags: linux, bash, design-patterns, grep

I am looking for a way to grep a file for a specific pattern with negative pattern in it. 
I have a log file witch reports units version and I want to see if there is a unit witch report version other then 26.

The closest I could get is :

> cat my.log | grep -i -e "version=0x[^2][^6]"

The above return a line contain "version=0x13" but not  return a line contain "version=0x23"

Is there a way to tell grep to do so ?

Thanks.

Comment: `grep -i 'version=0x[0-9]+' my.log | grep -v 'version=0x26'` ? This is not a programming question, [Unix/Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) seems more appropriate for it.

Comment: That won't work - the + needs to be quoted or you need -E.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interpret the pattern as a `perl` regular expression using the `-P` switch:

```
grep -iP 'version=0x(?!26)\d\d' my.log
```

Answer (score 7):

```
grep -i "version=0x[0-9]\\+" my.log | grep -iv "version=0x26"
```